# Printing packed structs in System Verilog

Tags: printing, struct, verilog, system-verilog, packed

I have a packed struct defined as shown below

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic bit1;
    logic [7:0] byte1;
} MyPackedStruct;

MyPackedStruct myPackedStruct;
```

Is there any SV built in function that I could use to print the structures similar to above but having many more fields, without having to write my own method to print each of the fields using a

`$display(...,myPackedStruct.field_name)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use %p - pretty print:

```
$displayb("%p",myPackedStruct);

'{bit1:x, byte1:xxxxxxxx}
```

which will print it as an assignment pattern, but you will not be able choose the fields or their ordering, or apply any other individual formating. %p is good for quick and easy displays, but most people eventually wind up writing a method to format it exactly the way they want it.

Comment: This is also valid for printing dynamic arrays.

Comment: You can use it for any unpacked array, but any large array you will probably want to format in some kind of loop.

Comment: Cannot edit this post: "Suggested edit queue is full"
But $displayb should be $display

Comment: @Bamban `$displayb` is what I wanted to get everything printed in binary radix.

Comment: OK! Sorry for the definitive comment I put, then. Do you know where I can find the doc about displayb in the LRM ?

Comment: Section _21.2 Display system tasks_ in the [1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595%5DIEEE)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `%p` formatting element.

```
$display("%p", myPackedStruct);
```

Output from Modelsim:

```
 # '{bit1:x, byte1:x}
```

See section `21.2.1.7 Assignment pattern format` in the [IEEE 1800-2012 SystemVerilog language spec.](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the section reference to the spec. I missed this section somehow.